# codeigniter session : php

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have one header file for the home page and the login page
in that header. I wrote this code on top of it

```
<?php
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==true ){
  redirect('home','refresh');
}else{
  redirect('home/login','refresh');
}
?>
```

but it keeps redirecting me to the same page and it shows nothing

Comment: Try placing the code in the __construct() part of the controller https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors make sure session is working also

Comment: Remove the else redirect on login page, its already in login page then why are you redirecting to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the else redirect on login page, its already in login page

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==true ){
  redirect('home');
}
```

except login, you can redirect the page :)

to differ the login page and home page just send the

```
$this->data["pagename"]="login"; in login function and
$this->data["pagename"]="home"; in home function
```

and in header

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==true ){
      redirect('home');
    } else { 
      if($pagename!="login")
       {
          redirect('home/login');
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!==FALSE){  
    redirect('home','refresh');
 }
  else{
   redirect('home/login','refresh');
 } 
?>
```

try the above code..

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

if (!$user_logged_in)
{
  redirect('home/login','refresh');
}else{

    redirect('home','refresh');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
put these line in every controller's `__construct` function

```
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !=true) {
      if ($this->router->fetch_class() != 'home' && $this->router->fetch_method() != "login") {
        redirect("home/login");
      }
    }
```